# Given "$ sudo pear install...." - what does the $ sudo mean?

Tags: syntax, package, installation, pear

I'm new to PEAR and trying out some packages. I've installed a couple but I ran into some documentation I don't understand.

I see instructions for installing packages such as:

```
pear install packagename
```

I also see

```
$ pear install packagename
```

and

```
$ sudo install packagename
```

I understand the first one but the other two ???

I read one place that they were putting the $ in front to clearly indicate the input  from the output on their examples. That is, lines with $ were what you entered at CLI and ones without were output from the entry.

Okay, fine, but what is sudo?

As I expect, entering $ or sudo or $ sudo gives the classic DOS error message which drove so many people crazy - xxx is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: `sudo` is a linux command/programm, it does not exist on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dollar sign `$` is to indicate that your user on a UNIX system is a non privileged user. Usually `#` indicates a privileged user, most typically root.

sudo is a tool that temporarily elevates authorized users to execute commands as root.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick reply. So - applied to a Windows command prompt window, they don't apply - right?

Comment: Wow - did I word that strangely??? What I meant is they don't apply to windows - right?

Comment: In terms of Windows, this would not apply ... however, if you need administrator privileges to install to the target you will need to start the command prompt with administrator privileges

Comment: Right - I understand that.